# What is crawler and how does it make a difference in the whole scrapy project?

Tags: python, scrapy

> https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#from_crawler
>   https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#crawler-api

After reading the official doc, I still have problems to understand `crawler`. I am very clear about other component(`spider`, `item&its loader`, `pipeline`, `settings`).

***But how and when the `crawler` affects to the whole process ?
How `crawler` can make it extendable ?***

For example : I write an item pipeline in order to populate the data to MongoDB.

```
import pymongo
class MyPipeline(object):
    collection_name = "mydb"

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings.get("MONGO_URI", "mongodb://test/"), crawler.settings.get("MONGO_DATABASE", "mydb"))

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.client_connection = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client_connection[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.client_connection.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(dict(item))
        return item
```

It seems like `pipeline` can access to `crawler` through `from_crawler` method. The method `from_crawler` return a initialized `pipeline` instance with settings.

Why not directly import my customized settings from `scrapy.settings` rather than use `crawler`?

Forgive me for asking too many questions:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation [states](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html)

> The main entry point to Scrapy API is the Crawler object, passed to extensions through the from_crawler class method. This object provides access to all Scrapy core components, and it’s the only way for extensions to access them and hook their functionality into Scrapy.

From looking [at the code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/crawler.py) I would have described the `Crawler` as "a core component that surrounds the user specific spiders and does the communication with other core components", because the `Crawler` has access to both `Spider` and `Engine`.

You would not want to import settings directly from `scrapy.settings`, because these would not include all correct settings according to the setting priorities. There are several places in scrapy where you can set settings with a very [specific precedence](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html):

> 1. Command line options (most precedence)
> 2. Settings per-spider
> 3. Project settings module
> 4. Default settings per-command
> 5. Default global settings (less precedence)

If you use `scrapy.settings.default_settings`, you can only get the lowest level of precedence. The project specific settings (already combined with the less precedence levels 4 and 5) e.g. would be retrieved with `scrapy.utils.project.get_project_settings`. As you can see, this is not part of `scrapy.settings` anymore.

Now the interesting part for your question is the spider specific settings (level 2). These are added exactly in the [class `Crawler`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/crawler.py#L35):

```
self.spidercls.update_settings(self.settings)
```

We can also have a look at the `BaseSpider` to see the implementation of `update_settings`:

```
@classmethod
def update_settings(cls, settings):
    settings.setdict(cls.custom_settings or {}, priority='spider')
```

Here we see that the settings indeed get added to the passed parameter (which is the `Settings` object from `Crawler`) with priority `spider`. It does not get returned, because `settings` is an object and thus passed by reference.

I hope that this goes into the right direction of your question, if not add a comment and refine the original question a bit. Then I will refine my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Is that means that if I don not write `from_crawl` method, the itempipeline instance created with default configs, and if I write `from_crawl` method returning a 'customized' pipeline instance with specified part like settings or signals hooked through the only entry ---- class crawler?

Comment: Do you have access to the settings at all, if you do not write a `from_crawler` method? You could get them from `scrapy.utils.project.get_project_settings` of course, but that's only the project settings then, not including spider or command line settings. On the other hand if you go via `def from_crawler(cls, crawler)` and then access `crawler.settings`, you get the fully applied settings from all precedences.